# Collectors.groupingBy with custom key name

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have class let's say CheeseMojo having various fields as follow:

```
public class CheeseMojo {
    private String recipies = "Recipies";
    private int age;
    private String name;
    private int submissionId;
    //getter/setter
}
```

Now I want to sort it based on submissionId using Collectors.groupingBy function, then below code snippet will do the job

```
Map<Integer,List<CheeseMojo>> map = new HashMap<>();
map = cheeseMojos.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CheeseMojo::getSubmissionId));
```

And the output will be something like below:

```
{1=[CheeseMojo@111111],2=[CheeseMojo@222222]}
```

But I want my output something like below:

```
{"Recipies1"=[CheeseMojo@111111],"Recipies2"=[CheeseMojo@222222]}
```

Please help

Comment: How do you want to have a map with two same keys?

Comment: What is the key, and what is the object being stored? You've described a map with no unique key and I'm not sure what object you're storing but I assume it is still a list.

Comment: it could rather be `{"Recipies"=[CheeseMojo@111111, CheeseMojo@222222]}`, but with an appropriate datatype such as `Map<String, List<CheeseMojo>>`

Comment: A map can't have two of the same keys. You should either use another data structure, or change your desired output.

Comment: Okay, sorry my mistake. Updated the query please check

Comment: My moto is to replace the submissionId with custom unique key.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just `map` the key either before collecting (lets say by creating an instance of a wrapper class that has

```
public class CheeseMojoWrapper { 
    private final String id;
    private final CheeseMojo wrapped;

    public CheeseMojoWrapper(CheeseMojo toWrap) {
        id = "Recipe"  + toWrap.getId();
        wrapped = toWrap;
   }
}
```

or using a stream on the `entrySet()` of your resulting map...